# Refresh on table using Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

I want to update my table data after updating and keeping the datatables function working.
When editing a row from my table with modal, when refreshing the table the datatable function no longer works, such as pagination and search option.

Table:

```
<table class="table table-responsive" id="table6">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Produto</th>
            <th>Stock</th>
            <th>Stock Minimo</th>
            <th>Ação</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php  do{ ?>
        <tr id="<?php echo $produto3["Id"]; ?>">
            <td><?php echo $produto3["Produto"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto3["Quantidade"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto3["Minimo"]; ?></td>
            <td><button type="button" id="<?php echo $produto3["Id"]; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $produto3["Id"]; ?>"  data-target="#add_data_Modal6" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit_data1" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } while($produto3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()); ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then I have the modal. When I save modal changes, I use the following js, where I refresh my table:

```
 function inserir_registo10() {
    var dadosajax = {
        'Id': $("#Id1").val(),
        'Produto': $("#Produto2").val(),
        'DescricaoUnid': $("#DescricaoUnid1").val(),
        'IdReqRec': $("#IdRec:checked").val(),
        'Quantidade1': $("#Qtd2").val(),
        'Quantidade': $("#Qtd1").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: './alterarproduto',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: dadosajax,
        error: function () {
            $(".error_message").removeClass('hide');
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $('.form10')[0].reset();
            $("#add_data_Modal12").modal("hide");
            $("#table6").load(" #table6 > *");
        }
    });
}
```

With the datatables function initially the table looks like this, where only shows ten records per page:
[image]

But when refreshing with this line in success:

```
$("#table6").load(" #table6 > *");
```

The datatables function no longer works and no longer shows the 10 records per page as shown in the image:

[image]

Comment: This is far too complicated for people to help you. Try to explain your problem more clear. What part of the code produces the problem. Explain what you are trying to achieve, and what currently is happening? Do you get error messages or just wrong data? Currently, you just have a lot of code, but you don't explain what's going wrong.

Comment: @Merijn dk  Returns no error. The problem is to refresh the table when I change the data. I refresh, but the datatables filters stop working. The problem is the success of the insert_register10 function. Then I want to update the table data by changing it, but datatables stops working. I will add images to the question with the results

Comment: @Merijn dk So can you better understand my problem?

Comment: @Merijn dk friend can't help me, I can't solve this problem

Comment: Adding 2 screenshots didn't make it more clear. As you can see by the number of reactions. Try to make the question more clear. There is way to much code. Slim it down. Try to be exact. What are you trying to do, and what is happening instead?

Comment: @Merijn dk I edited the question, helped to understand my problem? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem as follows.
Within the success of ajax I destroy the table datatble, then make an asynchronous request and render the table again with datatable.

Code:

```
   success: function(result)
    { 
    $('.form10')[0].reset();
    $("#add_data_Modal12").modal("hide");
    $('#table6').dataTable().fnDestroy();
    $.ajax({
       url: './atualizarprodutosrececao',
       type: 'get',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data){
         var linha = ``; 
         for(let item of data){ 
         linha += `<tr id=${ item.Id }>          
         <td>${ item.Produto }</td> 
         <td>${ item.Quantidade }</td> 
         <td>${ item.Minimo }</td>   
         <td><button type="button" id="${ item.Id }" data-id="${ item.Id }"  data-target="#add_data_Modal6" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit_data1" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></td>            
         </tr>`; 
         } 
         $("#table6 tbody").html(linha);
    $('#table6').dataTable({ 
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",                           
            "oLanguage": {
            "sProcessing": "Aguarde enquanto os dados são carregados ...",
            "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por pagina",
            "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro correspondente ao criterio encontrado",
            "sInfoEmtpy": "Exibindo 0 a 0 de 0 registros",
            "sInfo": "Exibindo de _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoFiltered": "",
            "sSearch": "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span>",
            "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst":    "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-fast-backward'></span>",
            "sPrevious": "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-backward'></span>",
            "sNext":     "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-forward'></span>",
            "sLast":     "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-fast-forward'></span>"
        }
     }
     });             
         }

        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Although your question isn't completely clear, here are my thoughts: I think the issue is that once you render NEW content onto your page via the AJAX-ed response, the JavaScript functions that control the table - filtering and searching - no longer work. Is that correct?

My guess, based on your info: You need to *re-initialize* the table JavaScript after a successful AJAX call. Here's some pseudo code to demonstrate:

You probably have some JS code to initialize your table, something like:

```js
$('.my-table').initialize()
```

Once you return the data via `$.ajax` and update the table, you simply need to re-run this initialization code in the `success` like:

```js
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function (result) {
    // Code to update your table here

    // And now we can reinitialize:
    $('.my-table').initialize()
  }
});
```

Comment: That is my problem. I have no code to initialize the table. I have the js that I put in the question and the code to render the table with datatables. How can I initialize the table to call the datatable function again?

Comment: What JS library are you using to generate the table in the first place?

Comment: I am using this library `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`. And for datatables I'm using `<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I'm trying like this `success: function(result){  $('.form10')[0].reset(); $("#add_data_Modal12").modal("hide"); $("#table6").load(" #table6 > *"); $('#table6').dataTable().fnDestroy(); $('#table6').dataTable(); 
in the ajax of the insert_register10 function button, but it doesn't work`

Comment: The problem is in the load. Load will not let Datatable start `$("#table6").load(" #table6 > *");`